# Вместо списка парсер выдаёт []

Tags: python, парсер

Я пишу парсер для одного сайта, вроде все правильно, делаю запрос и получаю вывод в консоль:

> []

```
def get_content(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('a', class_ = "actioncard_wrapper__3jY0N")


skins = []
for item in items:
    skins.append({
        'title': item.find('div', class_ = "styles_name__2_vei").get_text(strip = True)
        })

print(skins)
```

С тегами я не ошибся, они есть на странице. Не понимаю в чём дело(

Comment: А откуда берется `html`? С помощью `requests`? Зачем спрашиваю: просто тогда не будет исполняться js, а эти тэги скорее всего динамически создаваемые.

Comment: дополните вопрос, откуда берете html?

Comment: html беру с помощью requests со страницы сайта